# Simulating row_number() MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Can you help me with the `row_number() over partition` in MySql?

I've tried the script below and it doesn't work properly. I'm trying to select only the first product bought. The columns I am selecting are Client_id, product and purchase_date.

```
select * from(select * from (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_number,t.* 
FROM (select cliend_id,prod,purchase_date  from Mytable    
group by cliend_id,prod,purchase_date order by cliend_id,purchase_Date) asc) t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r)a)b;
```

Result:

```
Row_number  Client ID   Prod    Purchase date
1               1111    apple   11-Nov-10
2               1111    yougurt 11-Nov-11
3               1111    candy   11-Nov-13
4               2222    chocolate   11-Nov-09
5               2222    pear    9-Sep-09
6               2222    beer    12-Sep-10
7               2222    cheese  12-Sep-14
8               1234    apple   15-Nov-12
9               1234    candy   4-Oct-14
```

How can I get this result?

```
Row_number  Client ID   Prod    Purchase date
1               1111    apple   11-Nov-10
2               1111    yougurt 11-Nov-11
3               1111    candy   11-Nov-13
1               2222    chocolate   11-Nov-09
2               2222    pear    9-Sep-09
3               2222    beer    12-Sep-10
4               2222    cheese  12-Sep-14
1               1234    apple   15-Nov-12
2               1234    candy   4-Oct-14
```

Thanks,
Rodica

Comment: Shouldn't chocolate start the row number over at 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can "remember" the value of the `cliend_id` from the previous row, and use that information:

```
select (@rn := if(@c = cliend_id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@c := @liend_id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rownum,
       cliend_id, prod, purchase_date
from (select cliend_id, prod, purchase_date 
      from Mytable    
      group by cliend_id, prod, purchase_date
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @c := 0) vars
order by cliend_id, purchase_Date;
```

You should do the assignment of `@rn` and `@c` in the same statement, because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I receive an error regarding the if statement: #1064  -is not the right MySql server version to use near if(@c := @cliend_id, 1, 1))) as rownum

Comment: There was a missing comma.  That is a strange error, but it might fix it.

Comment: I don't receive an error anymore, but the rownum returned is 1 for all the values..it doesn't increment